# Website hold user details

Tags: javascript, angularjs, web-services, web

Using angularjs in the client , and c# in the server side. 
I want to learn how can i create a website with users.

I know how to store the data in the db.

My real question is how the site remember the user session
After refreshing. 
So the user dont need to login again.

Thanks guys.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Microsoft created a JWT (JSON Web Token) package for .NET Web API projects specifically for this purpose. And since you're using Angular.js, working with JSON is perfect.

There are plenty of tutorials for understanding how JWT works and securely saves a user's session like this one: https://scotch.io/tutorials/the-anatomy-of-a-json-web-token.

The idea is that your server sends your client/user a long encrypted string. The client saves it in their cookies and sends it to your server whenever you want to verify the user.

Most of the complicated details regarding encryption you don't need to worry about. Just follow the tutorials for setting up the exchange of the JWT tokens.

Comment: Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

Back in the days, we use cookies to do this.

In the Restful html5 world of today, we can use several other options.

Websql, Localstorage, IndexedDB.

Probably you are using something like JWT to store an authentication token you use to make authenticated api calls.

The way to go, or as i do is store that token in localStorage and then, inject in every call to the api.

Then in the angular run section i check if the user is authenticated checking if i have the token stored, and if is not, send to the login page.

```
angular.module('Scope', ['ui.router', 'ngStorage'])
    .run(function($localStorage, $state){
         if (!$localStorage.authenticationToken) {
            $state.go('login');
        }
     }
});
```

In this example, every time the app reloads, angular execute the run function, and checking if we have stored the token, if is not, send the user to the login webpage.

Comment: Great solution!